# Problem create listView in futureBuilder flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a listView in FutureBuilder. It's a List of Json Object, when i call the api, i receive the multiples objects but when i want created the list, I have differents errors.

For exemples :

A build function returned null.
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    Expanded

Image : [bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VAM8.png)

Theme model:

```
class Theme {

  int id;
  String name;

  Theme({this.id, this.name});

  factory Theme.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Theme(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Theme>> getThemes() async {
  String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme';
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List themesList = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Theme> themes = [];
    for(var themeMap in themesList){
      themes.add(Theme.fromJson(themeMap));
    }
    return themes;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load themes');
  }
}

}
```

Theme page :

```
class _Theme extends State<Theme> {
  var name;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Blackbox"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child : new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: new Text('Sélection du profil',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
              new Expanded(
                child : new FutureBuilder<List<t.Theme>>(
                    future: t.Theme().getThemes(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (!snapshot.hasData){
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }else{
                        new ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            for (var s in snapshot.data){
                              name = s.name;
                            }
                            return new ListTile(
                              title: new Text(name),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }                   
                    },
              )
              ),
              new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: new RaisedButton.icon(
                /*onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Technologies()));
                },*/
                label: Text('Suivant'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why your `builder` returns `return name;`? what kind of `Widget` is `name` variable?

Comment: I didn't attention, i delete this. But why my program,  pass by else condition and don't print the list.

Comment: isnt `FutureBuilder<List<t.Theme>` t null here?

Comment: @pskink When i start the debug program, i have my 3 json items, snapshot.length = 3, so I don't know..

Comment: @PeterHaddad when i test snapshot.data, i have : 
[Instance of 'Theme', Instance of 'Theme', Instance of 'Theme']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have missed `return` before `new ListView.builder` in FutureBuilder's builder method, so it is not returning anything but `null`.

So, your updated Theme page will like this:

```
  class _Theme extends State<Theme> {
     var name;
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Blackbox"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child : new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: new Text('Sélection du profil',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
              new Expanded(
                child : new FutureBuilder<List<t.Theme>>(
                    future: t.Theme().getThemes(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (!snapshot.hasData){
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }else{
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            for (var s in snapshot.data){
                              name = s.name;
                            }
                            return new ListTile(
                              title: new Text(name),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }                   
                    },
              )
              ),
              new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: new RaisedButton.icon(
                /*onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Technologies()));
                },*/
                label: Text('Suivant'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```